# Stream JSON with RxJS Observable

Tags: javascript, json, rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to understand a few things about RxJs. What I would like to do is consume some JSON data and immediately begin to render that data on the DOM as it's coming in. I've setup the stream request, response, and display. It's outputting every just fine but it's doing it all at once and not over time.

I want to start showing the data on the page as its coming in, instead of waiting for the whole file to complete then show at once which would create a long wait time.

```
//Cache the selector
var $resultList = $('.results');

//Gets the JSON (this will not be a static file,just for testing)
var requestStream = Rx.Observable.just("/results.json");

var responseStream = requestStream
    .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl))
             });

var displayStream = responseStream.subscribe(
    function(response) {
    //This maps to a Handlebars Template and puts it on the DOM
    $resultList.html(compiledTemplate(response)); 
            },
            function(err) {
                    console.log('Error: %s', err);
             },
             function() {
                    console.log('Completed');
             });




//Sample of the data from the JSON file
Object{
    beginIndex: "1"
    catId: "111"
    endIndex: "1"
    products: Array[100]

}
```

Comment: You have everything set up correctly, however, getJSON retrieves everything at once. In that sense, responseStream isn't a stream, its a fully formed object. And the promise resolved from jQuery.getJSON is just the entire response from the page. Your code would produce the actions you're looking for only if you were loading data from multiple sources at once (results.json, results2.json etc).

Comment: Is there a way to begin converting the single JSON file into an object and start looping through the Array on that object as its coming in? I'm looking for a way to stream the data incrementally as it's coming in and being processed.

Comment: You're really dependent on the behavior of the browser. The response comes in chunks which have a uniform size, but could begin and end anywhere in the data objects: 
[chunk 1, data: "[{object 1},{[ob]   [chunk 2, data: "[{ject2}{[object3...etc.... The broswer collect these and puts them in the right order. Now what you're asking about is getting into hacking the http protocol, which is overkill. If you want to parse this object by object, you'll want to connect to your server with a websocket and emit each member one by one, which is more streamy than a single get call.

Comment: Strike that last answer, it's probably sending everything in 1 big chunk, which, for our purposes is going to arrive at an instant in time. You're still looking for a websocket like behavior. (eg: http://socket.io)

Comment: So if streaming is not a good route, how about chunking? So take the first 10 in that array and send that off to be displayed. Then the next 10 and so on. So more like buffering/processing that in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand well, there are two relevant points to make:

1. you need to find a way to have a stream of objects from that file
   instead of one big object when you finish reading that file (`I want
   to start showing the data on the page as its coming in`). The
   mechanics of that would depend first on the structure of the source (file and file reading mechanism)
   than on Rxjs (is every line an object that can lead to information
   display etc.?). Once you have that 'minimum displayable unit of information' you can use Rxjs to buffer/process it if need be (do you want to display something for each object, or each 100 objects, or remove uncessary attributes etc.?)
2. you need to update your display incrementally
   as new data arrive. That means you need something like
   `$resultList.html($resultList.html() + compiledTemplate(response));`
   to append the new compiled `html` to the old one.

UPDATE : for chunking an array, you can have a look at this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/429vw0za/

```
var ta_result = document.getElementById('ta_result');

function emits ( who, who_ ) {return function ( x ) {
 who.innerHTML = [who.innerHTML, who_ + " emits " + JSON.stringify(x)].join("\n");
};}

function fillArrayWithNumbers(n) {
        var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
        return arr.map(function (x, i) { return {prop1: i, prop2:i, prop3:i} });
    }

var sampleObj = {
    beginIndex: "1",
    catId: "111",
    endIndex: "1",
    products: fillArrayWithNumbers(100)
}

console.log('sampleObj', sampleObj);

var result$ = Rx.Observable
  .from(sampleObj.products)
  .bufferWithCount(10)
  .map(function(mini_array){return {
  beginIndex: sampleObj.beginIndex,
  catId: sampleObj.catId,
  endIndex: sampleObj.endIndex,
  products: mini_array
  }})
  .do(emits(ta_result, 'result'));

result$.subscribe(function(){    });
```

You will then have a stream of objects with arrays of size 10 taken from the array of size 100.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. 1.)  I need to loop through the products Array on that object and pull in the other 3 properties on that object for the Handlebars template. So there will be one large object to consume.

Comment: Is your array so huge that it makes sense to chunk it (or the processing time of one item so long)? With Rxjs, you can easily chunk an array into a stream of 'mini'-arrays. So you could get that large object and output a stream of mini-arrays that you consume through an array-adjusted version of your current code. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect. If I could stream the chunks of that array to be displayed then I could get products on the page quicker rather than waiting for all 100 to be displayed at the same time.

Comment: answer using Rxjs posted. However, I wonder if you really have to use Rxjs. You could directly slice your array and do a simple loop. So you would not need streams at all here, just regular promises and regular synchronous code. Also : `flatMap` accepts promises, so you can write directly `return jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks like a good solution. You're definitely right about not needing Rxjs for this because at this point we're not trying to capture async request. Still trying to learn Rxjs and what it's best for.

Comment: In RxJS 5, bufferWithCount changed to bufferCount.  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md. Trouble...