# Merge in huge object to immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have the following operation inside my reducer:

```
case RECEIVE_DATE:
     return state.merge({
         isFetching: false,
         data: action.response
     });
```

It merges the current state with a new object, received from an API request. The thing is that this `action.response` object is huge - it's a tree, being more than 5MB in size. And the merge operation lasts more than 1s. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Do you need the entire response object in your store? The most obvious solution would be to just take the parts you need out of it - that said, I don't know your use case, so that might well not be an option!

Comment: Well, I actually need the whole response unfortunately :/ The server request takes a lot of time, I don't want to send it more than once.

Comment: The performance issue derives from an architectural issue, having to process a huge amount of data that comes from the server. You are doing your best, by processing the data only once, when that action fires, so you could either reduce the amount of times you fire the action or reduce the amount of data you get, like using pagination if the data is a collection of objects. Can we have more insight into what is the data and how often you need it to refresh?

Comment: It is a filesystem tree, displayed on a website. I can't really paginate a tree except for expanding nodes on click, and I want it to be instantaneous, so I'd like to have everything in a state ready to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream JSON with RxJS Observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373586/stream-json-with-rxjs-observable)